# Test if all three filetypes are present in a directory

Tags: bash

I want to detect that there is one of each of the following filetypes in a directory `.png` , `.txt`, and `.tar.gz`.

The following works correctly when testing for two of them

```
shopt -s nullglob
MYDIR=/some_dir
if [ $MYDIR/*.png] && [ $MYDIR/*.txt]; then
  echo "All files present"
else
  echo "At least one type is missing"
fi
```

But if I try to test all three using

```
if [ $MYDIR/*.png] && [ $MYDIR/*.txt] && [ $MYDIR/*.tar.gz]; then
...
```

or using

```
if [[ $MYDIR/*.png && $MYDIR/*.txt && $MYDIR/*.tar.gz ]]; then
...
```

then I don't get the correct behaviour (it still returns true even if one of the files is missing).

What is going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't test whether a filename globbing pattern matches using `[ ... ]` (and you lack space before the final `]` in all `[ ... ]` tests, so your code would not work anyway).

The way to do it is to perform the match and count the number of matching names.

```bash
shopt -s nullglob    # make globs expand to nothing if they don't match
shopt -s dotglob     # also match hidden names

error=false
for ext in png txt tar.gz; do
    set -- "$MYDIR"/*."$ext"
    if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
        printf 'Nothing matches "%s"\n' "$MYDIR/*.$ext" >&2
        error=true
        break  # possibly, unless you want the user to see all patterns that fail
    fi
done

if "$error"; then
    echo 'Can not continue' >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

If you feel you want to type more (or just need to preserve the existing list of positional parameters), you could uso a named array.  Change the `set --` line into `names=( "$MYDIR"/*."$ext" )` and the `"$#"` into `"${#names[@]}"`.  Note that all quotes are significant.

Answer (score 1):

**You absolutely need to use:**

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

before the test to avoid having false positives, like `$MYDIR/*.png` literally.

**But you cannot test a wildcard like this in a bash test, you need to test array instead:**

```
txt=( *.txt ) tgz=( *.tar.gz ) png=( *.png )
if [[ ${txt[@]} && ${png[@]} && ${tgz[@]} ]]; then
    echo SUCCESS
fi
```

**Another way to test wilcard existence with `compgen` hack:**

```
cd "$workdir"
if (compgen -W *.txt && compgen -W *.png && compgen -W *.tar.gz) &>/dev/null; then
    echo 'SUCCESS'
else
    echo >&2 'At least one filetype missed'
fi
```

**Don't forget to add bash's shebang:**

```
#!/bin/bash
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

---

`[[` is a bash keyword similar to (but more powerful than) the `[` command. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031 and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals. Unless you're writing for POSIX sh, I recommend `[[`

**Example of use:**

```
 [[ ${names[@]} ]] && echo 'SUCCESS'
```

no need to count number of occurrences like you tried.

Comment: Yes, apologies, I didn't realise it was critical, but I do indeed have that command just before the test.

Comment: Gilles can you provide a full example, which would work for all 3 filetypes?

Comment: It's inside a bash test, no need quotes @Stephen Kitt

Comment: DONE @teeeeee, check edited answer

Comment: Thanks to explain the vote down ^^

Comment: Hi Gilles. It wasn't my downvote. I wasn't quite sure how to translate your first solution (not the compgen version) into the case with multiple file extensions. That's the only reason I accepted the other answer. Thanks

Comment: Why not `compgen` ? You need to create 3 arrays, then `if [[ ${txt[@]} && ${png[@] && ${tgz[@] ]]; then echo SUCESS; fi `. You have sufficient reputation points to upvote.

Comment: Anyway, see edited post with this solution

Comment: Ah yes indeed, so there’s no word splitting.